# Show that the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_n}{n}$ converges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Show that if the partial sums of $s_n$ of the series $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_k$ satisfy |$s_n$| $\leq Mn^r$ for some $r < 1$

Then the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_n}{n}$ converges.

I really wanted to apply dirichlet's test here, but I cant seem to find a bound for $s_n$.

Any help or insight is deeply appreciated.

Comment: I think Abel summation will finish the problem, i.e. look at the proof of Dirichlet's test.

Comment: [$\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{a_n}{n} = \frac{s_N}{N}+\sum_{n=1}^{N-1} \frac{s_n }{n(n+1)}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation_by_parts)