# If $\sum\limits_{n=1}^∞u_n^2$ is convergent, then $\sum\limits_{n=1}^∞\frac{u_n}n$ is absolutely convergent

Tags: sequences-and-series, absolute-convergence

If $\{u_n\}$ is a sequence of real numbers and the series $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}u_n^2$ is convergent, prove that the series $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{u_n}{n}$ is absolutely convergent.

I have proved the series $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{u_n}{n}$ is convergent, but how to prove it is absolutely convergent?

Comment: I use latex math flashcards in android

Comment: This must be the 20-th time this question is asked here ...

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/112579, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2004794, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1048143, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2111557

Comment: Btw, if you have already proven that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(\frac{u_n}{n})$  is convergent then you are done: Just apply the same reasoning to $(|u_n|)$.

Answer (score 4):

One may use$$
2\cdot \frac{|u_n|}n \le |u_n|^2+\frac{1}{n^2},\quad n\ge1.
$$

Comment: (proof?).......

Comment: @JimmySabater We have$$
0\le\left( |u_n|-\frac1n\right)^2$$

Answer (score 4):

Apply Cauchy-Schwarz:$$\sum_{i=1}^N\left|\frac{u_n}n\right|\leqslant\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n{u_i}^2}\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n\frac1{i^2}}.$$